# AQH3223 does not turn off, even though there is no trigger voltage

Tags: solid-state-relay

I'm trying to design a computer-controlled power ON/OFF system for the device I'm working on. what I need is that I can turn device on or off with computer, and I have the means to apply 5v digital output from my computer (by using a DAQ). I found something about AQH3223 on the internet and bought the IC, tested it initially, and designed my PCB. But it seems like I tested it sloppy, because the device turns on, but does NOT turn off. I apply digital trigger to Power ON pins (pin 2), the input supply goes in pin 8 (VCC-IN), and is feeded to my device from pin 6 (VCC). Also, I have positive and negative supply voltages, thus the double design.

[image: the part of my circuit with AQH3223]

Now like I said, when I apply trigger, both SSRs work fine and turn on, but when  I put it off (by turning digital output to zero) they're still on. I even tested the ICs on breadboard (this time thoroughly), and got the same result. I apply 5v to trigger and an input feed to pin 8, and a LED is connected to pin 6 that is grounded. this time, the LED is always on unless I take down the feed voltage on pin 8. I also did some search and found this topic [Triac BTA316 does not turn off](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/211830/triac-bta316-does-not-turn-off) but they didn't find any answer either.

is there an easy fix for this? or better, another way to do this turning on and off?
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the top of the front page of the [data sheet](https://www.panasonic-electric-works.com/pew/eu/downloads/ds_61613_en_aqh.pdf) the part is described as: -

> Ideal for AC load control

This must have sounded alarm bells somewhere when you read the data sheet?

It uses a triac and this cannot be commutated off when operating at DC unless the load current drops below 25 mA (holding current).

Comment: True, and since I have both positive and negative voltages, it should be able to support AC voltages. don't you agree?

Comment: If the load current naturally falls below the holding current (25 mA) as specified in the data sheet then the triac will switch off. What you say about positive and negative voltages in your design is irrelevant because THIS DEVICE is an AC load device.

Comment: But my LED setup on breadboard hardly consumes even 10 mA. It's just one LED! also,my device doesn't use that much power either.

Comment: Go read about triacs if you don't believe me.

Comment: I'm not saying that, it's just that LED doesn't consume that much power, so it's below holding current (which is 25mA as you said).

Comment: Anyway, is there a better way to do what I want to do?

Comment: Read the data sheet - the 25 mA is a maximum limit - in reality it may be as low as 5 mA but the DS doesn't tell you that in the tables. Figure 7 implies a typical value about 6 mA at ambient but minimum value could be half of this.

Comment: Omron make quite small solid state relays that wil do what you want though you might have to bodge it onto your PCB. Panasonic may do too. Look for PCB mounting SSR or solid state relay and good luck.

Comment: Try omron mosfet relays https://www.omron.com/ecb/products/search/?cat=1&did=2&prd=mosfet&lang=en. These will out perform any triac based devices because they will switch on to a low resistance with low volt drop. And you can turn em off!